# How to control the point that the screen scrolls to when linking to another element in the same page

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a horizontal top sticky navbar 60px high.

On my page, I have links to locations on the same page with `<a href="#someTarget">Link</a>` leading to `id="someTarget"`

My problem is that when the resulting link is clicked, the page scrolls to the target heading, but it is at the very top of the screen, behind my sticky navbar.

How can I specify that the scroll add a 60px cushion so that the target is at the top of the viewable area, not at the top of the screen?

So far I have just been manually adding in my `id="someTarget"` a few lines above what I actually want to be the target, but this seems a pretty imprecise way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with using a CSS framework for this, [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/) has what you need. There is an offset option that you could use.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that offset feature of Scrollspy is definitely the kind of thing I'm looking for, although at this point I don't need its whole functionality, just the offset.  However, your answer gave me the terminology I needed to do some more searching, and I came across this page https://spigotdesign.com/smooth-scroll-offset-anchor-links-with-css/#smooth-scroll that I think will do the trick for me.  Thanks again.